# How can I solve this error?: networkx.exception.NetworkXError: ('Adjacency matrix is not square.', 'nx,ny=(10, 11)')

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I am trying to create a graph from a `numpy` array using `networkx` but I get this error: `networkx.exception.NetworkXError: ('Adjacency matrix is not square.', 'nx,ny=(10, 11)')`
Someone know how to solve it?

```
My_Diz = {'X120213_1_0013_2_000004': array([[  0.        ,  23.40378234,  30.29631001,  49.45217086,
         53.47727757,  74.32949293,  73.27188558,  93.85556785,
        132.31971186, 118.04532327,  88.1557181 ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,  34.41617904,  39.54024761,
         34.25713329,  51.79037103,  51.33810652,  70.9900316 ,
        109.76561471,  98.51724406,  69.76728919],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,  26.66788605,
         42.7133817 ,  79.11779461,  65.88325262,  89.68664703,
        125.91837789, 102.22926865,  71.58316322],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         22.98401022,  65.5730092 ,  44.53195174,  68.64071584,
        102.34029705,  75.76571351,  45.22368742],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,  43.0377496 ,  23.19245567,  47.19664886,
         83.42653241,  65.0762151 ,  35.66216118],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,  30.28626571,  29.1448064 ,
         64.72235299,  72.76481721,  56.93798086],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,  24.18622881,
         60.591058  ,  49.69530936,  27.61846738],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         39.02763348,  46.26701103,  40.06206332],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,  44.72240673,  62.0541588 ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,  30.69921172]])}
```

```
for k,v in My_Diz.items():
    G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(v)
    nx.draw(G)
```

Comment: An adjacency matrix is literally a table indicating for each node as row index, the distance to each node in column index. Thus it needs to be square.
Either your matrix is compacted to skip self edges, either you have to figure out the format for us to help you

Comment: @hl037_ Its not True this doesn't need to be square, to save memory you can skip to put the last row because you already have all the distances between that element and other in the column

Comment: in this case, it is triangular, but you can't do triangular with array (or there are 0...) moreover, the duplication  is what makes matrices faster than lists...

Comment: Then try to make it square

Comment: @hl037_ So I have another question for you if you have time. I've a dictionary that represent a graph how can i make it a adjacency matrix in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Matrix is not square. You have to give networkx a square matrix.
Since the matrix is (n × n+1), and it is triangular, you can do that :

```
for k,v in My_Diz.items():
  r, c = v.shape
  M = np.zeros((c,c))
  M[:r, :c] = v
  M[:c, :r] += v.T
  G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(M)
  nx.draw(G)
```